# Message from Webpage "finger print error code 10001"

Tags: internet-explorer

I am using secugen HAMSTER PLUS thumb device to capture thumb impression of my customers. Its been a while using the device and now my Internet Explorer Browser displays a message

> Finger print error code 10001

How do I solve my problem?

Recently I had the same problem but one of my friend resolved it by restoring some files belonging to some previous date C Drive which I don't remember. Where do I find that restore file in C Folder?

Comment: Hi, Tools>Manage Addons>Show all addons.... locate any addons from Hamster plus in the list, (there may be a number of entries) and make sure they are all enabled. Also ensure that Flash is enabled. On the web page that uses Hamster plus, make sure that ActiveX Filtering is not blocking any Controls - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2011/02/28/activex-filtering-for-consumers/